# Make a text entry fade out after input validation, then fade back in with original placeholder text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I'm setting up a splash page with a single email entry form.

Right now when a user enters an email the form fades out quickly and a thank you message fades in to replace it.  What I want to do is have the 'Thank You' fade out after a couple of seconds then have the form fade back in.

I can get it to happen, it's just that the form comes back with the email that was originally entered and I'm having a hell of time trying to figure out a way of replacing the email address with the original placeholder text.

Here's the from:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="sendEmail">
    <div class="forms">
        <div class="buttons" id="buttons">
            <button type="submit" id="submit"></button>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="text_box" id="text_box">
            <input type="text" name="emailTo" id="emailTo" value="   Your Email Here"
            onfocus="this.value=''" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div class="answerBox">
    <div style="display:none;" id="thanks">Thank you!</div>
</div>
```

And this is the Jquery I'm using to handle the fade in, fade out after successful validation:

```
if (hasError == false) {
    $.post("adduser1.php", {
        emailTo: emailToVal
    }, function (data) {
        $(".buttons").fadeOut(200);
        $(".text_box").fadeOut(200, function () {
            $("#thanks").fadeIn(200)
        });
    });
}
return false;
```

I tried this:

```
$.post("adduser1.php", {
    emailTo: emailToVal
}, function (data) {
    $(".buttons").fadeOut(200);
    $(".text_box").fadeOut(200, function () {
        $("#emailTo").text("   Your Email Here", function () {
            $("#thanks").fadeIn(200))
        });
```

But It doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, `#emailTo` is not affected by `.text` as it's an `<input>` element. Replace `.text` with `.val`:

```
$("#emailTo").val("   Your Email Here")
```

**Second**, you're trying to bind `#thanks.fadeIn` to the end of .text (or .val) change. Since it's an instant action, this is unnecessary (and I think also not proper jQuery syntax). Just place `$("#thanks").fadeIn(200)` in the next line:

```
function (data) {
  $(".buttons").fadeOut(200);
  $(".text_box").fadeOut(200, function () {
    $("#emailTo").val("   Your Email Here")
    $("#thanks").fadeIn(200))
  });
}
```

**Working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2A8b/)**

Comment: You may or may not (but probably did) notice that I'm kind of new to web development.  Thanks man, you've single handedly finished my project.  Hats Off!